# append a struct B (which inherits from the struct A) to a slice of structs A

Tags: go, inheritance, struct, append, slice

I have a struct B which inherits from the struct A. I have another struct C (which contains a slice of structs A) and I want to append B to C.

```
package main

type A struct {
    target string
}

type B struct{
    A
    values []int
}

type C struct{
    Cols []*A
}

func main() {

var values = []int{1,2,3}
var col1 = C{} 
var col2 = &B {
    A: A{
        target: "txt",
    },
    values: values,
    }

col1.Cols = append(col1.Cols, col2)

}
```

When running this code, it generates an error: cannot use col2 (type *B) as type *A in append

What's wrong please ? I'm newer

Ps: sorry for my bad English

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go. If you want to append (pointers to) Bs, you have to have a slice of (pointers to)  Bs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

col1.Cols is type *A, col2 is type *B, col2.A is type A, if you want to add new element to the slices, they should be of the same type.
so if you change the last statement to

```
col1.Cols = append(col1.Cols, &col2.A)
```

it will work.